# Overlaping MapViews doesn't seem to behave correctly

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a MapView in an activity and another MapView in a view that will pop up in front of the activity when click some button). The problem is that when the view pops up, instead of showing a new Map in the assignated area, this area is empty (and transparent), so, it is visible the map of the activity, not the view's (no matter if I put some bg color).

Anyway, trying to solve this, I created a simple Activity, which has two overlaping MapViews, and on a button click toggles one or other in front.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Toggle" />


    <RelativeLayout     android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip">

             <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mapview1_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                    android:background="#ff0000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
                 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapview1"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mapview2_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                    android:background="#00ff00"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip">
                 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapview2"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            try { MapsInitializer.initialize(this); } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) { }

            mapView1content = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapview1_content);
            mapView2content = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapview2_content);

            mapView1 = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
            mapView1.onCreate(null);
            mapView1.onResume();

            mapView2 = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview2);
            mapView2.onCreate(null);

            Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ii%2==0){
                mapView1.onPause();
                mapView2.onResume();
                mapView2content.bringToFront();
                mapView1content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mapView2content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                mapView2.onPause();
                mapView1.onResume();
                mapView1content.bringToFront();
                mapView2content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mapView1content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            ii++;
        }
    });


    }
```

The result is not the expected one, when MapView2 is in focus, it still shows an image from MapView1 in front (although its not clickable)

[image]

UPDATED:

I tried this in many devices and it seems a problem of IceCream Sandwich or lower...

Comment: Have you tried invalidate, reload or something like that to recreate the view ??

Comment: Yes, I tried invalidate, postInvalidate, but no luck. Even setting visibilities to gone, doesn't work

Comment: Did you also use `recreate` method ??